# How to set ListView background?

Tags: android, listview, background

I want to set white as a background color in my `ListView`.

This is my code:

```
rect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ArrayAdapter adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter(Drejeskive.this,
                             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                             digits);
        ListView vl = new ListView(getApplicationContext());
        vl.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.list_bg);
        vl.invalidate();
        layout.addView(vl);
        vl.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
});
```

rect - it is my button

`list_bg` is below

```
<item android:drawable="@color/white" />
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I wonder why people doesn't answer this user's questions

Comment: I found solution. I changed   vl.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.list_bg);
            vl.invalidate();
on vl.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255)); And it works

Comment: @MithunP Like you _really_ do?

Comment: @Viktoriya: You can answer your own question and mark it as correct. That might help other with the same problem.

Comment: check whether your colors.xml contains <resources><color name="white">#FFFFFF</color></resources>

Answer (score 3):

You should use `setBackgroundResource(R.color.myRow_red)` instead of that and `setBackgroundColor()`. In your example background color is assigned with the ID instead of the actual color described in the resources

Comment: When I use vl.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white); it doesn't work

Comment: have to use this setBackgroundResource(R.color.myRow_red) not setBackgroundColor() read my comment once more :)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources> <color name="transparent_blue">#80004488</color>
<color name="black">#ff000000</color> bla bla..bla.. </resources>

Comment: Thanks to all of you
You were right. setBackgroundResource(R.color.myRow_red)-it is the right answer.